# Call a method from an activity to a fragment of another activity. What is the proper way?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, callback

This might have already answered but I am still troubling with a function like this. Let's say I have **activity A** and **activity B**. B holds a `viewpager` with several fragments in it. I would like to call a function in the fragment held by **activity B** from **activity A**.

I used callbacks many times to communicate between activites and fragments but every single time it was only the fragment and its holder activity. I do not want to make a static method (the callback listener cannot be static anyway) so it causes a headache for me. The simple static solution to make a static method in the fragment and have it called from the other actually works very well, but I am not sure if it was a good idea as I need to change several things static.

So communicating between **Activity B** and its fragments is ok, but I cannot call this method in **Activity A**.

**Activity B:**

```
public class ActivityB extends FragmentActivity implements Fragment1.OnWhateverListener                           
                          {  
...

@Override
    public void onWhateverSelected(int position) {  
         //stuff, here I can call any function in Fragment 1
    }

}
```

The following code snippet is a wrong solution (doesnt even work) but makes a better picture what I would like to do.

**Activity A:**

```
ActivityB ab = new ActivityB ();
ab.onWhateverSelected(number);
```

So how can I do this?
Thank you!

**EDIT**

**Activity A:  the method I call**

```
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString("ID", id); // the data to send
   Intent frag_args = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   frag_args.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
   frag_args.putExtra("args", args);
   startActivity(frag_args);
```

**Activity B:**

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
    processIntent(getIntent()); //last line of onCreate, always gets called here
    }


     @Override
     public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);
            processIntent(intent); // this never gets called here only in OnCreate
     }

     private void processIntent(Intent intent) {
                Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("args");
                if (args != null) { // check if ActivityB is started to pass data to fragments
                    String id = args.getString("ID");


            Log.i("ID_FROM", "id: " + id);   //works well
                        if (id != null) {
                          List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
                          fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
                       //NULLPOINTER for the following line 
                          FragmentMainDiscover fr = (FragmentMainDiscover) fragments.get(0);  
                          fr.RefreshHoverView(id);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right to stay away from statics. Way too risky, for visual objects that may or may not be on screen.

I would recommend going through activity B, since it is the parent of your target fragment. Create an Intent that starts activity B, and include an intent extra that tells activity B what it should do to the target fragment. Then activity B can make sure that the fragment is showing, and pass the information on to it.

One other idea to pass the info to the fragment is to use setArguments, rather than direct calls. This is a nice approach because Android will restore the arguments automatically if the activity and its fragments are removed from memory.

Does this make sense? Do you want the code?

EDIT

To use arguments, you still need to have activity A go through activity B. This is because activity A doesn't know if activity B, and all its fragments, is running unless it sends it an Intent. But you can include data targeted for the fragments, by putting them inside the intent. Like this:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    public static final String KEY_FRAG = "frag"; // tells activity which fragment gets the args
    public static final String KEY_ARGS = "args";
    public static final String KEY_MY_PROPERTY = "myProperty";

    public void foo() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(KEY_FRAG, "frag1Tag"); // which fragment gets the data
        args.putCharSequence(KEY_MY_PROPERTY, "someValue"); // the data to send

        // Send data via an Intent, to make sure ActivityB is running
        Intent frag_args = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        frag_args.setClass(this, ActivityB.class);
        frag_args.putExtra(KEY_ARGS, args);
        startActivity(frag_args);
    }
}

public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //TODO configure activity including fragments
        processIntent(getIntent()); // this call is in case ActivityB was not yet running
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        processIntent(intent); // this call is in case ActivityB was already running 
    }

    private void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra(ActivityA.KEY_ARGS);
        if (args != null) { // check if ActivityB is started to pass data to fragments
            String fragTag = args.getString(ActivityA.KEY_FRAG);
            if (fragTag != null) {
                Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
                frag.setArguments(args);
                //TODO either show the fragment, or call a method on it to let it know it has new arguments
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = "frag1Tag";
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String value = args.getString(ActivityA.KEY_MY_PROPERTY);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question with the code I inserted. The problem that I get a nullpointer for the indicated line. When I use this code in another context it finds the fragment correctly. Which I also dont know that the NewIntent overriden method never gets called, only the OnCreate runs. Which might cause the nullpointer probably.

Comment: Anyway I do not want to start the other Activity, just call the method. I can put       frag_args.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); but this clears the present activity.